# Wordpress register_post_type parameters

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking at the codex for registering a custom post type and I don't quite get what this parameter does

```
function codex_custom_init() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
```

What exactly does the second parameter do? I can't find it anywhere from googling.

'name' => _x('Books', **'post type general name'**)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress l18n _x() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802283/wordpress-l18n-x-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a description. The description for 'Books' is 'post type general name'.